# Missing required parameters for [Route: admin::sliders.index] [URI: admin/slider-groups

Tags: laravel

In my laravel application whenever I go to this route: admin/slider-groups I get the following error message:

We have following routes.

```
/slider-groups

/slider-groups/1

/slider-groups/1/sliders/create

/slider-groups/1/sliders/10/edit
```

[image: route]

blade.php

```
<a href="{{ route('admin::sliders.index') }}" class="mr-1">
```

web.php

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'admin',
    'as'     => 'admin::',
], function() {
    Route::resource('slider-groups', 'Admin\SliderGroupController');
    Route::prefix('slider-groups/{sliderGroup}')->group(function(){
        Route::resource('sliders', 'Admin\SliderController');
    });
});
```

SliderGroupController.php

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->search) {
        $sliderGroups = SliderGroup::search($request->search)->paginate(30);
    } else {
        $sliderGroups = SliderGroup::paginate(30);
    }
    if ($sliderGroups->count() == 0 && $request->search ) {
        msg()->warning('دقت کنید', 'هیچ رکوردی یافت نشد.');
    }
    return view('slider::admin.groups.index', compact('sliderGroups'));
}
```

To note I'm not including all the html code of index.blade.php as it's too long the only blade code is from what i have pasted.

Comment: Can you show the controller method as well? `index` method in `SliderGroupController` to be specific.

Comment: `SliderController` or `SliderGroupContoller`

Comment: just the index method in `SliderGroupContoller`

Comment: Does `php artisan route:list` work?

Comment: I see this demo .  https://i.stack.imgur.com/V60uv.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230693/discussion-between-irankhostravi-and-p-k-tharindu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are prefixing `siderGroup`, you need to pass the `$sliderGroup->id` to each route in

```
Route::resource('sliders', 'Admin\SliderController');
```

For example do:

```html
<a href="{{ route('admin::sliders.index', $sliderGroup->id) }}">Link</a>
```

instead of:

```html
<a href="{{ route('admin::sliders.index') }}">Link</a>
```

Comment: Then I have a problem